# push multiple Line Text as one message in a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to push a text consisting of multiple lines as one message into a kafka topic.

After I enter:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic myTopic
```

and copy my text:

```
My Text consists of:
two lines instead of one
```

I get two messages in the kafka topic, but I want to have just one. Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`kafkacat`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html) for this, with its `-D` operator to specify a custom message delimiter (in this example `/`):

```
kafkacat -b kafka:29092 \
        -t test_topic_01 \
        -D/ \
        -P <<EOF
this is a string message 
with a line break/this is 
another message with two 
line breaks!
EOF
```

*Note that the delimiter **must** be a single byte - multi-byte chars will end up getting included in the resulting message [See issue #140](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/140)*

Resulting messages, inspected also using kafkacat:

```
$ kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -C \
         -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k\t\nValue (%S bytes): %s\n\Partition: %p\tOffset: %o\n--\n' \
         -t test_topic_01

Key (-1 bytes):
Value (43 bytes): this is a string message
with a line break
Partition: 0    Offset: 0
--

Key (-1 bytes):
Value (48 bytes): this is
another message with two
line breaks!

Partition: 0    Offset: 1
--
% Reached end of topic test_topic_01 [0] at offset 2
```

Inspecting using `kafka-console-consumer`:

```
$ kafka-console-consumer \
    --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 \
    --topic test_topic_01 \
    --from-beginning

this is a string message
with a line break
this is
another message with two
line breaks!
```

(*thus illustrating why `kafkacat` is nicer to work with than `kafka-console-consumer` because of its optional verbosity :)* )

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible with `kafka-console-producer` as it uses a Java Scanner object that's newline delimited.

You would need to do it via your own producer code

Answer (score 1):

With Console-consumer you are obviously running tests for your expected data coming from client. If it is a single message, better keep it as a single string by adding a unique delimiter as identifier. e.g.

{this is line one ^^ this is line two}

Then handle the message accordingly in your consumer job. Even if client is planning to send multiple sentences in message, better make it in a single string, it will improve serialization of your message and will be more efficient after serialization.

Comment: It's better not to rely on random delimiters within messages at all, though

Comment: Agree, in fact if test case contains having multiple lines, use "\n" delimiter to simulate this scenario. e.g. {this is line one \n this is line two}